# Constraineed Maximization Problem

Tags: optimization

I am creating a game, and have run into quite a tricky problem which I have been wrestling for days. I have been able to turn into somewhat mathematical terms (bare with me, I'm a programmer not mathematician) -- but I am no closer to a solution.

`var constants = [1000, 100, 10]; // arbitrary length, arbitrary positive numbers
var contributions = [?, ?, ?]; // an array of each constants respective contribution`

Given an array of `constants`, I am trying to generate an array of `contributions` which represents each `constants` contribution to a pool.

`SUM(constants[i] * contributions[i]) === pool`

That is to say, each constant multiplied by their contribution ... summed up is known as the `pool`.

Here are the constraints I have to obey:

`FOREACH i in constants.length:
   constants.length * (constants[i] * contribution[i]) isLessThanOrEqualTo pool`

That is to say, if I get the amount of constants I have .. multiply it by constants contribution ... it will always be less than or equal to the size of the pool.

And the last constraint:

`All contributions must be less than or equal to 0.01`

In other words, no constant can contribute more than 1% of its value to the pool.

Given these constraints, what I want to do is construct my array of `contributions` in such a way to maximize `pool`.

What I am looking for, is a function which turns an array of `constants` into an array of `contributions`. If anyone could give me any pointers, place to start, library suggestions .. or even work through how this problem would be solved for the example: `constants = [1000, 100, 10]` -- i would be highly appreciative.

Comment: You may want to review your constrain. If you add all constrains you would have $constants.length*pool\leq constants.length*pool$. So all the constrains have to be equality. It follows easily that you can have only one choice of constribution (given the maximal is .01). In your example, contribution array is $[.0001,.001,.01]$.

Comment: Hm! Wow, great answer -- you are right. Why when I enter this:

Maximize p = 1000x + 100y + 10z subject to
x <= 0.01
y <= 0.01
z <= 0.01
3*(1000x) - 1000x - 100y  - 10z <=  0
3*(100y) - 1000x - 100y  - 10z <=  0
3*(10z) - 1000x - 100y  - 10z <=  0

into: http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html

It solves as p=0   (which as you demonstrated, is not the case)

Comment: Your input is not "standard". I put "Maximize p = 1000x + 100y + 10z subject to 
x <= 0.01, y <= 0.01, z <= 0.01, 
2000x - 100y - 10z <= 0,
 - 1000x +200y - 10z <= 0,
 - 1000x - 100y +20z <= 0" 
and everything's good.

Comment: btw, can you let me know about your game when finished? It may be a good example for my students :-)

Comment: Sure, although I'm not sure how suitable it will be. My game is: http://wwww.moneypot.com ... and I'm trying to create a new version, in which players all play at a single table and pick their own initial bet size.

I then want to create a "last cashout bonus" scheme, where peoples bonus is proportional to how much they bet ... in such a way that is fair for the casino and the player. However, the maths is totally doing my head in..

Comment: @QuangHoang if you post your first comment as an answer, I'll mark as the solution. This was indeed my problem. I re-evaluated what I was doing, and you're totally right

Comment: Questions are closed when they are bad or duplicate questions. If you found a solution of a question, however simple it turned out to be, that's a different matter. Just mark the answer as accepted by clicking checkmark next to it, and everybody can move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add all constrains you would have $constants.length∗pool≤constants.length∗pool$. So all the constrains have to be equality. It follows easily that you can have only one choice of contributions (given the maximal is .01). In your example, contribution array is [.0001,.001,.01].